# Select random image

Tags: php

I've got two images and I am trying to use PHP to select one at random. I have the following code:

```
<?php 

    $img_one = "http://www.domain.com/image-swap/image-one.png";
    $img_two = "http://www.domain.com/image-swap/image-two.png";

    $images = array( $img_one, $img_two);

    $rand_image =  array_rand($images, 1); 

?>

<img src="<?php echo $rand_image ?>"> 
<img src="http://www.domain.com/image-swap/image-one.png">
```

The problem with this code, is that the image's URL becomes a number: `1` or `2`.

Comment: [Documentation for array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php), you should try reading it sometime. "Picks one or more random entries out of an array, and **returns the key (or keys)** of the random entries."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way. `$rand_image` consists of randomly selected index number. So pass it inside the array as key value like `<?php echo $images[$rand_image]; ?>`

```
<?php

$img_one = "http://www.domain.com/image-swap/image-one.png";
$img_two = "http://www.domain.com/image-swap/image-two.png";

$images = array( $img_one, $img_two);

$rand_image =  array_rand($images, 1);

?>

<img src="<?php echo $images[$rand_image]; ?>">
<img src="http://www.domain.com/image-swap/image-one.png">
```

Comment: **+1** Great to see answers that include *why*, rather than just fixing the code.

Comment: I have given the explanation. Can you please check before comment.

Comment: Huh?  I was praising you for the explanation.  Read the comment before following up.

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $rand_image ?>">
```

to this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $images[(int)$rand_image -1] ?>">
```

Comment: the problem is that you pass only the number, you have to print the image inside an array with a position (your random number) @tmyie